# How to configure mod_wsgi so that RockMongo is accessible in a subdirectory (404 error)?

Tags: apache, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

**Desired Behaviour**

I want to be able to access RockMongo at `localhost/rockmongo`.

**Current Behaviour**

I am getting:

```
Error: 404 Not Found
Sorry, the requested URL 'http://localhost/rockmongo' caused an error:
Not found: '/rockmongo'
```

**Environment**

- Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon
- Apache

  - Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
  - Server built:   Jul 22 2014 14:36:38
- `mod_wsgi`
- `virtualenv`

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf**

```
WSGIPythonHome /var/www/html/ENV
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html:/var/www/html/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/var/www/html/wsgi
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/wsgi/application

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**Directory Permissions**

/var/www

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Nov 23 08:58 www
```

/var/www/html

```
drwxr-xr-x 10 me me 4096 Nov 26 23:46 html
```

/var/www/html/rockmongo

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 me me 4096 Jun  6 23:04 rockmongo
```

**Apache Error Log**

There are no errors relating to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, but I'd love confirmation that this is the right way to do it and doesn't create any security issues for RockMongo or interfere with other aspects of `mod_wsgi` functionality.

I added the `Alias` line and the `Directory` block below.

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf**

```
WSGIPythonHome /var/www/html/ENV
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html:/var/www/html/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/var/www/html/wsgi
<VirtualHost *:80>

# for all content in static folder - css, js, img, fonts
Alias /static/ /var/www/html/wsgi/static/

# for rockmongo
Alias /rockmongo /var/www/html/rockmongo

<Directory /var/www/html/rockmongo>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/wsgi/application

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```